# Spellchecker error source tree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Everytime I open sourcetree I get this annoying popup:

[image]

> "SourceTree detected the following invalid Dictionary file references.
> These are known to cause performance issues.
>
> Do you want to remove these invalid dictionaries?"

If I click on 'Yes' -> close sourcetree -> reopen it -> the popup appears again.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

I'm using version 1.9.10.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug in SourceTree. That doesn't appear to have a workaround (see the quoted sections below for why).

There are two bugs listed on Atlassian's own JIRA:

[SRCTREEWIN-6664](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-6664) has [this comment](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-6664?focusedCommentId=1000639&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-1000639) from one of the Atlassian staff members:

> SourceTree is reporting that there are invalid file entries listed in the registry for the Windows spellchecker. If these are not deleted it can cause performance issues in SourceTree. The dialog should list the files to be deleted. However it appears it is possible to get empty entries in the registry, something we didn't see during testing. We are working to improve the notification's presentation of this.

[SRCTREEWIN-6674](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-6674) is also about this bug and points out that it's SourceTree that is causing the problem.

> It appears that SourceTree itself is creating the empty entry.
>   If I use regedit to remove the extra empty line (one of the 2 newline characters) from _ Global _ under
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Spelling\Dictionaries`
>   then SourceTree will start up without the error message the next time. But when it starts, the extra empty line will be created again in that registry entry!

[source](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-6674?focusedCommentId=1001880&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-1001880)

> When SourceTree starts it creates a new dictionary file (e.g. `xljwxlxe.dic`) under `%localappdata%\Temp` and adds the dictionary to the previously mentioned registry entry (along with the illegal empty line).
>
> ... snip ...
>
> When SourceTree closes, it removes the dictionary again, but leaves the empty line in the registry.

[source](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-6674?focusedCommentId=1001884&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-1001884)

So basically, the only workaround is to remove the empty lines from the registry entry that SourceTree is checking. But after you do that, opening SourceTree will just add the blank lines back again and cause the same problem next time you open SourceTree.

**Update:** As Osiris M. points out in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41998428/4397397), there's a possible solution over on [Atlassian Answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/44898447/answers/45392009), but it seems to work for some people and not for others. It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 15):

Just got [a working solution from the Atlassian forum](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/44898447/answers/45392009).

**I did the following:**

1. Delete all *.dic files in your user temp location: `%localappdata%\Temp`
2. Open SourceTree and you will get the same notification, but this time the program will indeed show the wrong entries.
3. After agreeing to delete the wrong entries, the notification won't show again.

Comment: Seems to work for some people but not for others. It didn't work for me. It showed the missing dictionary instead of showing an empty list, but after choosing to delete it, it now shows an empty list again :(

Comment: @reduckted Yes. For me the problem always gets back after a while. Around a couple of weeks and I have to do the same process again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I have a French windows 10, and use English spell check under SourceTree.
I fix the error just by installing the English language package for windows 10.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Until Atlassian fix the two bugs, my solution was to schedule an hourly task which runs the following Windows batch file.

To correct the problem of two newline characters instead of one, simply querying the registry and re-adding the same data solves the problem.

If slow performance is still experienced in Sourcetree, run the task more often such as every half an hour.

```
:: fix-dictionaries.bat
@echo off

set regPath="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Spelling\Dictionaries"
set regName="_Global_"

for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY %regPath% /v %regName%') do set "regData=%%~b"

REG ADD %regPath% /t REG_MULTI_SZ /v %regName% /d "%regData%" /f
```